# Cosmic ray-proof programming

Tags: code-challenge

Cosmic rays are [bad for computers](//stackoverflow.com/q/2580933/5223757). They corrupt RAM, and that causes problems. Computer chips are shrinking, and that makes them [more vulnerable](//stackoverflow.com/q/2580933/5223757#comment2588767_2580963) to the cosmic rays. We will not give in to these high-energy particles. Turing-completeness shall live on!

### Task

Your task is to write a Turing machine. But not just any Turing machine: your Turing machine has to be cosmic ray-proof! At any time in your program's execution, exactly one bit will be flipped in its memory-space. Your program must continue executing normally regardless.

Your Turing machine must have an arbitrarily-sized tape (in both directions), initialised to `NUL` (`0`).

#### Input

The input will be a list of tuples, each conforming to the following format:

```
state value new-value direction new-state
```

The items of each tuple are as follows:

- `state`, `new-state`: States are strings of arbitrary length. In practice they won't be very long. A blank space will not be used in a state name.
- `value`, `new-value`: Each value is exactly one byte. It may be any character from `NUL` to `DEL`.
- `direction`: The direction to move. Can be `l` (left), `r` (right) or `n` (stay still).

#### Output

Output should be the blocks of tape that have been written to, from left to right.

### Scoring

Your program will be scored by `number of errors / number of rays`. Cosmic rays are simulated by randomly changing one bit in the program's working memory whilst it is running. Only one ray will hit the program per execution. Lowest score wins.

Your program must run without cosmic rays hitting it.

### Cosmic Ray algorithm

```
prog = debug.run("program");
for (states = 0; !prog.exited; states++) {
    prog.step(1);
}
output = prog.output;

raystate = randint(0, states); // [0 - states)
prog = debug.run("program");
prog.step(raystate);
addr = prog.memory.randaddress();
bit = randint(0, 8);           // [0 - 8)
addr.flipbit(bit);
prog.run();
if (output != prog.output) {
    print("Failed");
} else {
    print("Succeded");
}
```

Comment: What's the objective? I don't see any winning criterion.

Comment: This is still in dire need of the sandbox.

Comment: @feersum I'm working on `csmcry32` and `csmcry64`. Once I've done that, I'll make the *nix version.

Comment: Since two people have voted to reopen, I presume that they think it's clear what the task is. Could one of them state it in their own words? Because I have no idea what the Turing machine we're being asked to write is supposed to do.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It's meant to run a program which is given as input.

Comment: So are you asking for a universal Turing machine which is capable of executing TMs with arbitrary symbol sets? Or a schema for creating a universal Turing machine given the symbol set over which the machines it emulates will execute? And in any case, given that every reasonable answer will get a perfect score, what's the tie-breaker?

Comment: @PeterTaylor ... Why will every reasonable answer get a perfect score?

Comment: And no, I just want a Turing machine that supports 256 symbols and an infinite tape. But the tape doesn't actually have to be infinite, and the program has to output the used sections of the tape.

Comment: Re scoring: if you're going to go to the hassle of writing a universal Turing machine for a complex symbol set, adding a basic best-of-3 error correcting code isn't much more work. Re output: hang on. The question asks us to write a Turing machine. Turing machines do all I/O via their infinite tape. "*Output the used sections of the tape*" doesn't make any sense. It will leave a representation of the emulated machine's tape (and probably the machine itself) on its own tape, surely?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Emulated machine?

Comment: How should output work then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40624/discussion-between-peter-taylor-and-wizzwizz4).